# How does HDInsight cluster maps to Azure Storage as HDFS?

Tags: azure-hdinsight

I have a fair idea of how Hadoop works as I have studied the on-premise model since that's how everyone learns. In that sense the top level idea is fairly straightforward.We have a set of machines (nodes) and we run certain processes on each one of them and then configure those processes in such a way that the entire thing starts behaving as a single logical entity that we call a Hadoop (YARN) cluster. Here HDFS is a logical layer on top of individual storage of all the machines in the cluster. But when we start of thinking of the same cluster in cloud , this becomes little confusing. Taking the case of HDInsight Hadoop cluster , lets say I already have an Azure Storage account with lots of text data and I want to do some analysis so I go ahead and spin a Hadoop cluster in the same region as the storage account. Now the whole idea behind Hadoop is that of processing closest to where data exists. In this case when we create the Hadoop cluster , a bunch of Azure Virtual Machines start behind the scenes with their own underlying storage (though in the same region). But then, while creating the cluster we do specify a default storage account and a few other storage accounts to be attached where data that is to be processed lies. So ideally the data that is to be processed needs to exist on the disks for the virtual machines. How does this thing work in Azure? I guess the virtual machines create disks that are actually pointers to azure storage accounts (default + attached) ? This part is what is not really explained well and is really cloudy. So lot of people including myself are always in dark when they learn the classic on-premise Hadoop model academically and start using cloud based clusters in the real world. If we could see more information about these virtual machines right from the cluster Overview page from the Azure portal , it would help the understanding. I know it's visible from Ambari but again Ambari is blind to Azure, it's an independent component so that is not very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

There is an underlying driver which works as a bridge in mapping the Azure Storage as HDFS to other services running in HDInsight.

You can read more about this driver's functionality in the below official page.

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-azure/index.html

If your Azure Storage Account is of type ADLS Gen 2 (Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2) then the driver used is different and can be found under the following official page. This offers some advance capabilities of ADLS Gen2 to beef up your HDInsight performance.

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-azure/abfs.html

Finally, as same as your on-prem Hadoop installation, HDInsight too has a local HDFS that is deployed across your HDInsight cluster VM Hard drives also. You can access this local HDFS using URI as below.

```
hdfs://mycluster/
```

For example you can issue the following to view your local HDFS root level content.

```
hdfs dfs -ls hdfs://mycluster/
```